# Using the :general with use-package sometimes doesn't work

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

I started converting my `evil-define-key` calls to use the `:general` extension to `use-package`, and sometimes they work, and sometimes not. Re-evaluating the `(use-package ...)` s-expression doesn't change the behavior, so I'm assuming I have a configuration issue.

This code works, as typing `g l` in the normal mode state, calls the `link-hint`:

```
  (use-package link-hint
    :bind
    ("s-o" . link-hint-open-link)

    :general
    (:states 'normal :keymaps 'global-map
             "gl" 'link-hint-open-link
             "gL" 'link-hint-copy-link))
```

However, the following code, which looks very similar, does not add a `g p` binding in normal mode:

```
  (use-package consult
    ;; Enable automatic preview at point in the *Completions* buffer. This is
    ;; relevant when you use the default completion UI.
    :hook (completion-list-mode . consult-preview-at-point-mode)

    :init
    ;; Use Consult to select xref locations with preview
    (setq xref-show-xrefs-function #'consult-xref
          xref-show-definitions-function #'consult-xref)

    :general
    (:states 'normal :keymaps 'global-mode-map
             "gp" 'consult-yank-pop
             "gs" 'consult-line))
```

I don't believe the issue is with the `:general` extension, but really with general.el adding to the `g` sequence, as the following doesn't work either:

```
(general-define-key
  :states 'normal :keymaps 'global-mode-map
  "gp" '(consult-yank-pop :which-key "yank pop")
  "gs" '(consult-line :which-key "visual search"))
```

And perhaps the issue isn't with general at all, as the following doesn't work either:

```
(evil-define-key 'normal 'global-mode-map (kbd "gp") 'consult-yank-pop)
```

So I guess my real question is why `gl` works, but `gs` and `gp` do not.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know why my initial code sometimes works, a reliable way to change the global map with the `:general` extension to `use-package` is to drop the `global-mode-map`. In other words:

```
(use-package consult
  ...
    :general
    (:states 'normal
             "gp" 'consult-yank-pop
             "gs" 'consult-line)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first snippet of code works because you typed the name of the keymap correctly: "global-map". In the others you typed "global-mode-map", which does not exist.